# APK generated by react native does not make requests to the server on Android 9 device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, axios

At the outset I must admit that I am a newbie in ReactNative world. I am developing  a mobile app with React Native. The app does exactly what I wanted to achieve. I have tested it on the emulator. It works fine. I built the apk file, installed  on two android devices ( with android 6 and 7). It works fine on both the devices. However when I install the same apk on a Galaxy S8 device (with Android 9) the app does not  work.

The app starts with a get request (I use axios library) to the remote server and renders the fetched data. (The spinning icon is shown with ActivityIndicator until the request is complete). When I open the app on Galaxy S8 it just shows the spinning icon forever. I checked the server log and found out that no request from this device has ever been made. On the other hand I can see the requests from other two phones.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set Android Compile Version and Target Version to 28.

Comment: @hongdevelop You mean at build.gradle? Which variables do I have to change exactly? Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

Comment: Change url from http to https

Comment: @hong develop. Your solution worked. Thank you very much. But there is a new problem now. I cannot install the apk on older Androids (6 or 7)

Comment: OK you can try `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 26`

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try.

Please add **allowBackup** and **useCleartextTraffic** lines in the application tag of the android manifest.

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 />
```

Please let me know if this solution doesn't work.